# Can I attach metadata to NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a pipeline-style image processing program. I would like to log all intermediate steps it takes.

Currently, it loads all images from a directory and stores them all as NumPy arrays (for further processing with OpenCV). I would like to attach a string tag to each array to see the name of the original file it came from, so I don't have to drag that name everywhere. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: You could just monkeypatch the array: `x._my_metadata = "stuff"`.

Comment: @jme it wouldn't let me. `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_name'`

Comment: Ah, true, `ndarray`s don't have `__dict__` attributes, I forgot. You'll want to subclass `ndarray`, then. See [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array). Alternatively, I'd just make a namedtuple with a "metadata" entry and an "array" entry.

Comment: @jme thank you. I chose subclassing eventually. Since making OpenCV return instances of the subclass instead of the raw NumPy arrays would be a big pain in the ass, I suppose, there is no way to do any better.